# How to set up acceleration in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing my own "Dinosaur game" (like in Chrome) in Unity. My dinosaur, however, accelerates way too fast. Can you help me to find a problem in my code?

Here the code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb2d.Cast(Vector2.down, hitBuffer);
    float distance = hitBuffer[0].distance;
    if (distance > minMoveDistance)
        Fall();
    else
        Move();
}

void Fall()
{
    transform.Translate(fall);
    fall += Physics2D.gravity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    fall = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(fall, 90 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}

void Move()
{
    transform.Translate(move);
    move.x += (acceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Make `acceleration` a smaller value?

Comment: Is its fall accelerating too fast or is its move accelerating too fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html
- You can use to acceleration using addForce for rigidbody of unity
- By Rigidbody

```
public void Update()
{
    if (hasAcceleration)
    {
         // AddForce(Vector2 force, ForceMode2D mode = ForceMode2D.Force);
         // 
         rigidbody2D.AddForce(force, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
}
```

- or by your self,

```
public void AddForce(Vector3 force)
{
    Vector3 f = force;
    f = f / mass;
    acceleration += f;
}

public void AddForce(Vector2 force)
{
    AddForce(new Vector3(force.x, force.y, 0.0f));
}

public void UpdateMovement(float deltaTime)
{
    velocity += acceleration;
    acceleration *= 0;

    movement = velocity * deltaTime;

    transform.localPosition += movement;
}
```